# C# regex for contains neither this and that

Tags: c#, regex

I try to create an regex in C# for allow only string with more than 3 char BUT if it starts with 'sch' it schould have a minimal length of 6 and if it starts with 'st' or 'ch' it should have a minimal length of 5.

The second part is pritty easey but the first part (all others length of 3) is more complicated:

```
"(^(SCH).{3})|(^(ST).{3})|(^(CH).{3})|^(!SCH).{3}"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And where this `^(!SCH).{3}` regex comes from?

Comment: This means, if it not start with 'sch' the minimal length should be 3! It does not work and it misses the definition for 'ch' and 'st'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
@"^SCH.{3,}|^(?:ST|CH).{3,}|^(?!S?CH|ST).{3,}"
```

`{3,}` in `.{3,}` would repeat the previous token that is `.` (*which matches any character*) 3 or more times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/5)

`^(?!S?CH|ST).{3,}` if the string doesn't startswith `SCH` or `ST` or `CH`, then match those strings only if it has at-least three characters.

Comment: or `@"^(?:S?CH|ST).{3,}"`

Comment: It doesn't work, should match any other string longer then 3 char

Comment: OP asks: `allow only string with more than 3 char`, not only ones starting with SCH/ST/CH

Comment: @"^SCH.{3,}|^ST.{3,}|^CH.{3,}" matches indeed all starting with 'sch' having at least 6 chars but I need in addition that all other strings should have at least a length of 3!

Comment: try `@"^SCH.{3,}|^(?:ST|CH).{3,}|^.{3,}"`

Comment: Doesn't work, matches `SCH`, `ST `, `CH ` disregarding length

Comment: @StefanLicht does the negation rule applies only to the strings startswith `SCH`? What about `CH` or `ST`? If we do it only for `SCH` then it causes the `ST`, `CH` rules to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't use a regex for that.  Just use standard `string` operations.

```
bool IsValid(string str)
{
    if(str.StartsWith("st") || str.StartsWith("ch"))
        return str.Length >= 5;
    if(str.StartsWIth("sch"))
        return str.Length >= 6;
    return str.Length > 3;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly that what I currently have but I want to bind it as an RegEx match for a UI control so I need this C# code snippet as regex